# regex to find these values?

Tags: python, regex

I have a line like this:

```
a = "switchport port-security mac-address 000a.1111.2222 vlan 43"
```

I want to stick the mac and vlan numbers into a list like so:

```
["000a.1111.2222","43"]
```

I thought something like the below would do it, any ideas?

```
import re
a = "switchport port-security mac-address 000a.1111.2222 vlan 43"
b = re.findall("([a-fA-F0-9]{4}[\.]){2}([a-fA-F0-9]{4})|(\d+)",a)
print b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a slightly different solution using `split` in case you don't know for sure that you can grab elements at index 3 and 5 of the `split`ted string (in this case, it grabs the `split`ted elements just after `"mac-address"` and `"vlan"`, respectively):

```
In [1]: a = "switchport port-security mac-address 000a.1111.2222 vlan 43"

In [2]: splitted = a.split()

In [3]: [x for i,x in enumerate(splitted) if i > 0 and splitted[i-1] in ["mac-address", "vlan"]]
Out[3]: ['000a.1111.2222', '43']
```

Answer (score 2):

without regex, just use split.

```
a = "switchport port-security mac-address 000a.1111.2222 vlan 43"

split_list = a.split()
required_info = [split_list[3],split_list[5]]
print required_info
>> ["000a.1111.2222","43"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need a grouping :

```
>>> a = "switchport port-security mac-address 000a.1111.2222 vlan 43"
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'mac-address (.*).*vlan (.*)',a)
[('000a.1111.2222 ', '43')]
```